# Why are the rational numbers not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

I am trying to understand why the rational numbers are not continuous.

Given two rational numbers $a$ and $b$, I can always find a number $c = \frac{a+b}{2}$ between these two numbers. So when I plot the rational numbers as a line, this is a steady line (unlike natural numbers, which are obviously not continuous). Why are they not continuous?

Comment: Between $a$ and $b$ you have also irrationals.

Comment: Continuity is a property of functions. You seem to ask why the rational numbers are not connected (or path connected).

Comment: Why do you think that they are **not** "continuous" ? But we speak of "continuity" for a function...

Comment: You can define a function $f: \mathbb{Q} \mapsto \mathbb{Q}$ and there is no problem in applying the usual definition of continuity to that function!

Comment: @iblue, *define formally* what is "continuous" for you.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: My book ("Taschenbuch der Mathematik") states that "The set of real numbers is continuous, which means that every point on the number line has assigned a real number. This is not true for the rational numbers". How does one define this formally?

Comment: OK! Not very formal, but your book says that there is a *bijective correspondence* between points of the line (the geometric thing) and real numbers.

Comment: The property you are investigating seems to be completeness rather than continuity. The square root of $2$ is not a rational number.

Comment: It's a little hidden in one of the answers below: the property you look at is called "dense" not "continuous".

Comment: This winds up being a question about infinities and infinitesmals. The rational numbers can come arbitrarily close to an irrational but can never equal it -- so the "line" can look arbitrarily continuous, but will never actually be so; there will always be a gap at the irrational. No matter how close you look, rationals can't equal an irrational until the number of digits becomes infinite... at which point you've just reinvented irrationals.

Comment: @keshlam: The reals can then be augmented further, creating the hyperreals, which are even more dense. What's special about the reals is not that they're in some sense maximally dense. There are denser systems. What's special about the reals is the completeness property.

Comment: The question and all the answers so far are written in terms of point sets, which is fine -- that's the most common way of talking about this kind of things these days. But it's not the only way. Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis (SIA) has a completely different way of talking about what is meant by a continuum. Here's a pretty accessible treatment: http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3307 In SIA, a curve is locally identical to a line, and lines and curves cannot be broken up into point sets.

Comment: $π$ is in one of the rational numbers' gaps, just as $1.5$ is in one of the natural numbers' gaps.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla That seems to be rather a different property than those I am used to seeing, which are defined in terms of *internal properties* (i.e. connectedness, completeness). How do you prove that a line in the sense of Euclid is isomorphic to the real numbers (rather than the surreals or rationals)?

Comment: @Mario Carneiro, a formal definition of "line in the sense of Euclid" is required first. I'm not an expert, but I think that any isomorphism proof requires second-order logic. In any case, all this started by the bad but comprehensible use of the word "continuous".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You argue that the integers are "not continuous", which means that they are a *disconnected* set. By the same reasoning the rational numbers are *disconnected*, see http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Totally_Disconnected/Proof_1.

Comment: If you just want to point to a proof that the rationals are disconnected, shouldn't you link to http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_not_Connected instead?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, you are right. But I thought the link with totally disconnected gives even more information.

Answer (score 25):

You are completely right in that the notion of holes depends on what you can put between your numbers. There is always a bigger set. The integers are contained in the rationals, which are contained in the real numbers, but those themselves can be viewed to have many holes, called non-standard real numbers (e.g. infinitesimals).

In order to give the ideas of “holes” and “being without holes” a meaning, you have to define what the total set of your numbers should be. If you say you want all rationals, that is fine. **But** there are properties which are only fulfilled by bigger sets of numbers.

For example you can easily construct a right triangle with legs of length $1$. Then the length of the hypotenuse will not be a natural number like $1$ nor even a rational number. It is $\sqrt2$, a hole in the rational numbers. The same happens if you want to measure the circumference of a circle with rational radius.

As for the statement in your book, $\sqrt2$ and $π$ are probably numbers they want on their number line. However what exactly the set of numbers on the number line is, depends on how you define it. There is not a right or wrong way. Just more and less useful ones for doing math with.

In analysis now, there are still more things you would like to describe by numbers. For example you want to find zeros of a function. For the real numbers the following property holds:

> Let $f: ℝ→ℝ$ be a continuous function and $a<b$ real numbers such that $f(a) < 0 < f(b)$. Then there is a $x$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

This is not true for the rational numbers. The reason is, you can always make your interval $(a, b)$ smaller and smaller, keeping $f(a) < 0 < f(b)$, thereby closing in on the zero of $f$. That way you get a sequence of (rational or real) numbers $(a_n)_{n\inℕ}$ which is *Cauchy* (meaning the distance $\vert a_m-a_n\vert$ gets arbitrary small for $m$ and $n$ big enough). But only in the real numbers there will always be some limit $x$ contained in all the intervals $(a_n, b_n)$. This property is called *completeness*.

Comment: "There is always a bigger set. The integers are contained in the rationals, which are contained in the real numbers, but those themselves can be viewed to have many holes, called non-standard real numbers (e.g. infinitesimals)."  I agree fully with your last sentence, but the first is not obvious to me, since it implies the hyperreal numbers, which do disconnect the reals in Non-Standard models, can themselves be rendered disconnected in another, still more inclusive set of numbers, & those numbers too can be rendered discrete, ad inf.. This seems to imply the "absolute continuum" notion.

Comment: @WdFusroy I must admit, that sentence is not very rigorous. Now that you question it, I cannot say whether it is actually true in any reasonable interpretation. The universality of non-standard real numbers will certainly make it difficult to construct an even “bigger” set. Feel free to prove or disprove it. Though not in this comment thread ;-)

Answer (score 21):

I would prefer to keep two pieces of standard jargon separate, and distinguish being a *continuum* and being *continuous*.

Continuity is a property of functions. There's a standard "epsilon-delta" explication of the notion of continuous function. And the function $x^2\colon \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$  (for example) defined over the rationals is just as good a continuous function as its counterpart defined over the reals.

So you can have continuous functions defined over rationals; but the rationals are not a continuum. Why not? The notion of a continuum has its roots in geometry, and -- in the barest headline terms -- the fundamental thought is that certain geometric constructions, even repeatedly indefinitely, will have determinate results. In particular, if we "sum" finite lines by laying them end to end, then so long as the result is bounded, then it is indeed another finite line (how trite that sounds!).

But when we arithmetize geometry, this turns into the thought that, for numbers apt for measuring lines in a true continuum, any increasing sequence of numbers-apt-for-measuring-a-line which is bounded above must converge to a limit which is another number-apt-for-measuring-a-line. Now, a bounded above sequence of rationals need not converge to a rational limit (it might converge to $\sqrt{2}$). By contrast, a bounded above sequence of reals will converge to a real limit. So the reals form the analogue of a geometrical continuum and the rationals don't.

(Sometimes it is said that forming a continuum is a matter of not being *gappy*. But the notion of gappiness is too blunt an instrument here. After all, the rationals are of course *dense*, i.e. between any two there is another -- so in *one* good sense they are not gappy. So we need to distinguish lack-of-gaps meaning denseness, and lack-of-gaps meaning being a continuum.)

Comment: +1 for giving such a cogent, precise, yet non-technical explanation that nails the OP's question.

Comment: Just a note on the terminology, the OP cites a German title (Taschenbuch der Mathematik), so that will have used the word "stetig", which usually is used for "continuous", hence the literal translation. It has also a (related but) different meaning, old-fashioned, but honoured by none less than Dedekind: "... der Art, daß das Gebiet der Zahlen dieselbe Vollständigkeit oder, wie wir gleich sagen wollen, dieselbe _Stetigkeit_ gewinnt, wie die gerade Linie." (Stetigkeit und Irrationale Zahlen, R. Dedekind, 1872)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I can help to tidy up some of the terminology. A linearly ordered set is called a [*linear continuum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_continuum) if it has no gaps or jumps. A *jump* is a cut where both sides have endpoints; an ordering without jumps is called *dense*. A *gap* is a cut where neither side has an endpoint; an ordering without gaps is called *complete*.

The natural numbers have jumps, but no gaps; they are complete, but not dense. The rational numbers have gaps, but no jumps; they are dense, but not complete. The real numbers have neither gaps nor jumps; they are a continuum.

Some authors (and translators from other languages) use the English adjective "continuous" to describe a continuum. As some of the comments and other answers point out, this usage may be confusing, since the adjective "continuous" is also used for functions, and the meaning isn't quite the same.

Comment: You bring up some important things, but this would be a much better answer if you defined "cut" (and the "sides" thereof) in the text of your answer (if not also "linearly ordered set"). I know what you mean, but I think a reader who is not already familiar with these concepts would not know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 3):

We have here two "intuitive" concepts of "having **no** gaps", but they are not the same, when defined rigorously.

*(1)* A function $f$ is *continuous* at some point $c$ of its domain if the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $c$ exists and is equal to $f(c)$ [usual mathematical formula ...].

The function $f$ is said to be continuous if it is continuous at every point of its domain. If the point $c$ in the domain of $f$ is not a limit point of the domain, then this condition is vacuously true, since $x$ cannot approach $c$ through values not equal $c$. Thus, for example, every function whose domain is the set of all integers is continuous.

As said above, you can define a function $f : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ (for example, the $id$ function, where $id(x)=x$) and there is no problem in applying the usual definition of continuity to that function.

*(2)* A *linear continuum* is a linearly ordered set $S$ that is densely ordered, i.e., between any two members there is another, and which "lacks gaps" in the sense that every non-empty subset with an upper bound has a least upper bound.

The real line is a linear continuum under the standard < ordering. Specifically, the real line is linearly ordered by <, and this ordering is dense and has the least-upper-bound property.

The set $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers, which is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, has not the least-upper-bound property; in this "view" it has gaps !

Answer (score 2):

The big difference between $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ stays only in one simple property.

Without considering any particular construction, we can define $\Bbb Q$ to be the $\bf field$ $\bf of$ $\bf fraction$ $\bf of$ $\bf the$ $\bf integers$ $\Bbb Z$: I say 'the', because all fields of fractions are equal up to isomorphisms. So our $\Bbb Q$ happens to be an  (infinite) ordered field with the Archimedean property;

Now, leave apart the Archimedean property, and consider an ordered field with the following additional property: $$\text{every non-empty bounded above set has a least upper bound.}$$
You've so just obtained $\Bbb R$! In fact, it can be shown that there indeed exists one such field. And all $\bf complete$ (with complete we refer to this last property) $\bf ordered$ $\bf field$ are equal up to isomorphism. The Archimedean property now follows automatically from the completeness. We can then think of $\Bbb Q$ to be a subset of $\Bbb R$, since $\Bbb Q$ is isomorphic to a subset of $\Bbb R$.

*Archimedean/Archimedian property:*

The Archimedean (or Archimedian) property basically says that the set $\Bbb N$ is not bounded above in $\Bbb R$. Surely, if we consider $\Bbb N$ by itself (i.e., not embedded in $\Bbb R$) as an ordered set, then it is unbounded above by definition (in fact, for each natural $n\in\Bbb N$, there exists also the number $n+1 \in\Bbb N$, which is defined to be greater than $n$).
Now, let's embed $\Bbb N$ in our $\Bbb R$. It can be done by induction. Let $\phi:\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$ be a map such that 
\begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
   \phi(1)=1\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{to 1 we associate the multiplicative identity element of the field $\Bbb R$};\\
   \phi(n+1)=\phi(n)+1\qquad\text{the number 2 goes in $1+1$, the number 3 goes in $1+1+1$, $\dots$)}
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
(since now then we simply denote with $n$ the number $\phi(n)$ and we consider $\Bbb N$ only as a special subset of $\Bbb R$.)
As before, we know that there is no natural $m$ such that $m>=n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$, in fact nothing has changed in the immersion of $\Bbb N$ into $\Bbb R$. But, how do we know that there isn't any $r\in \Bbb R$ such that $r>=n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$? In other word, how can we be sure the set $\Bbb N$ in unbounded above in $\Bbb R$? Well, this is simply a consequence of the completeness property we assumed for $\Bbb R$.

**proof:**$\,\,\,\,\,$suppose $\Bbb N$ were bounded above. Since $\Bbb N\ne \emptyset$, there would be a least upper bound $\alpha$ for $\Bbb N$. Then
$$\alpha\ge n\qquad\text{for all $n$ in $\Bbb N$}.$$
Consequently 
$$\alpha\ge n+1\qquad\text{for all $n$ in $\Bbb N$},$$ since $n+1$ is in $\Bbb N$ if $n$ is in $\Bbb N$. But this mean that $\alpha -1 \ge n$ for all $n$ in $\Bbb N$, and *this* mean that $\alpha -1$ is also an upper bound for $\Bbb N$, contradicting the fact that $\alpha$ is the least upper bound. $\blacksquare$

One can show that this property is equivalent to the fact that, given an $\varepsilon>0$ it exist a natural $n$ such that $\dfrac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Can you state briefly what the Archimedian property exactly is for completeness' sake?

Comment: I've just edited my answer: see above :)

Comment: one more question: when you say, "You've so just obtained ℝ!" here, does your argument assert that $\mathbb{Q}$ does not contain non-empty bounded above sets with a least upper bound? I'm having trouble understanding why not. Couldn't you just choose the largest element of a set contained in $\mathbb{Q}$ as its upper bound? I guess I'm really asking what situation yields a supremum not in $\mathbb{Q}$ but in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I sort of get it from the wikipedia article: "An example of a set that lacks the least-upper-bound property is ℚ, the set of rational numbers. Let S be the set of all rational numbers q such that $q^2 < 2$. Then S has an upper bound but no least upper bound in ℚ: If we suppose p ∈ ℚ is the least upper bound, a contradiction is immediately deduced because between any two reals x and y (including √2 and p) there exists some rational p', which itself would have to be the least upper bound (if p > √2) or a member of S greater than p (if p < √2)."

Comment: No, I'm not saying that "$\Bbb Q$ does not contain non-empty bounded above sets with a least upper bound", I'm only saying that not every bounded above subset of $\Bbb Q$ has a least upper bound in $\Bbb Q$. "Couldn't you just choose the largest element of a set contained in $\Bbb Q$ as its upper bound?" Well, no: how do you know such 'largest' element exists? From your example you see that indeed there isn't a largest $q$ such that $q^2<2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have *many* holes: all the irrationals. In fact, *more* holes than points!

Comment: But the holes are not included in the rational numbers. If I just define "apple" as $1 < \text{apple} < 2$, there is also a hole in the irrationals.

Comment: (A) Obviously! (B) Define *where exactly* is "apple". Between 1 and 2 isn't enough. (C) See my comment.

Comment: $\text{apple} < \sqrt{2}$ but if $x$ is a real number and $x < \sqrt{2}$ then $x < \text{apple}$. Okay?

Comment: @jwg I don't know if you're aware, but that's a particularly good demonstration that the reals (in any formulation) are not the final ordered field.  That is, $\rm{apple} = \sqrt{2} - \frac{1}{\omega}$ is a perfectly good definition of $\rm{apple}$ that satisfies all the above properties.  Generally, when the reals aren't enough, look to the surreals.  :)

Comment: @Ptharien, the funny thing is the surreals aren't  complete: "on the other hand, they fail the completeness property of the reals in the most extreme way: every nonempty set of Surreals has an upper bound and no least upper bound." (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221334/whats-the-difference-between-hyperreal-and-surreal-numbers)

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Yeah, they're not complete, otherwise they'd be *isomorphic to* the (Dedekind) reals, rather than *a strict supercollection* of them.  I think completeness (either Cauchy or Dedekind) is overrated, anyway.  :P

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to think about it: The rationals are 'full of holes', so to speak, because there are some lengths out there in the world for which there is no corresponding rational number. For example, you probably know that the diagonal of a unit square has length equal to the square root of 2, which cannot be written as a quotient of integers. Intuitively speaking, the idea of the real line is to 'fill in the gaps' so that for every length there exists are corresponding real number.

The property of the rational numbers you've noticed, that you can always find a rational number between any two real numbers, is referred to as the *density* of the rational numbers in the reals.